# Substring from an escape character onwards

Tags: postgresql, substring, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL and I need to truncate a text string, I need to show from an escape character (:) onwards.

**I'm trying something like that:**

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING ('CATEGORIA DE TRABAJOS: EJECUTIVO' FROM '%#":#"%' FOR '#');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=# select split_part('CATEGORIA DE TRABAJOS: EJECUTIVO',':',2);
 split_part
------------
  EJECUTIVO
(1 row)
```

just split by first found delimiter?..

Comment: Genius!!! Correct and functional solution. Thank you so much Vao Tsun!!!